# При создании переменной в xaml, cs ее не видит, что делать?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Вот код места создания переменной из xaml:

```
                            `<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="#a35624">
                                <Button Text="-" Clicked="Minus" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontFamily="Fox"/>
                                <Label x:Name="Count_L" Text="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontFamily="Fox"/>
                                <Button Text="+" Clicked="Plus" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontFamily="Fox"/>
                            </Grid>`
```

Все это находится в CollectionView, может ли это быть из за этого?

Comment: Да, из-за этого.